# Why Mask brush in Sculpt mode won't paint mask?

Tags: modeling, interface, sculpting

I'm trying to create a layer on the head of my character from which I'm going to create  its hair.

My problem is that whenever I use the *Mask* sculpt brush, neither nothing is colored nor any change is applied. I think this problem is caused by the fact that something is blocking me from using Sculpt mode. In fact if you look at my screenshot closely there is a dotted line along the *Toolshelf* menu and in the bottom of 3D View editor.

Can anybody help me please?

[image: screenshot of mesh]

I use [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWyOSUAdrak) as reference.

It s a timelapse video therefore i'm not able to see all the settings the author uses.

P.S. I'm not sure if a material or a UV map is needed, anyway I don't have them yet created for this model.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ? Then we can take a closer look at your problem.

Comment: whenever I try to upload it, the file just lies there for ages so i' ll just e mail it to you.